# angularJS - Data is not displayed in unordered list

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning angularJS and have some simple example with 2 Views and Controller.
My main page defines controller and route and displays views.
View page should display text field, unordered list, adds new data to unordered list.
Also, it should filter a `<ul>` based on what is typed in text field.
However, it does everything except of filtering `<ul>`

Here is the code:
Main Page:

```
<body>
<div>
 <div data-ng-view=""></div>   
</div>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

    demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.customers =
        [
            { name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix' },
            { name: 'Jamie Riley', city: 'Atlanta' },
            { name: 'Heedy Wahlin', city: 'Chandler' },
            { name: 'Thomas Winter', city: 'Seattle' }
        ];


        $scope.addCustomer = function () {
            $scope.customers.push({ name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city });
        };
    });

        demoApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                .when('/view1', {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'Views/View1.htm'
                })
                .when('/view2', {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'Views/View2.htm'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/view1'
                });
    });

</script>

</body>
```

This is one of the views that should displays `<ul>`:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    Name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'name'">
            {{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}
        </li>
    </ul>

    <br />
    Customer Name:<br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
    <br />
    Customer City:<br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
    <br />
    <button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
    <br />
    <a href="#/view2">View2</a>
</div>
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />`

to

`<input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />`